# How do I fix "Expected expression"

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

.h

```
IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@end
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)calculate {                           **This is the line with the problem**
int x = ([textField1.text floatValue]);
int c = x*([textField2.text floatValue]);
   [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, it looks like a bomb went off in your implementation. For one, you seem to be missing the `@implementation` directive in the beginning of the .m. Then, you call `[super viewDidLoad];` from within an IBAction, when it should be in your viewDidLoad method which is missing.

Additionally, you never added a closing brace `}` at the end of your IBAction.

Your .h file should look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
}
@end
```

Your .m should look like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)calculate {
    int x = ([textField1.text floatValue]);
    int c = x*([textField2.text floatValue]);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: It still says that it expects an expression in the - (IBAction)calculate { line and I'm missing @end????

Comment: Yup did... but I don't know why xcode thinks I'm missing an @end when it is there?